# How to delete multiple documents with specific value in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to delete many docs with specific categoryId value from my collection, but I'm doing this in a wrong way I think.

```
async deleteCol(id: string) {
    const cars: firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot 
      = await this.db.collection('cars', ref => ref.where('categoryId', '==', id)).ref.get();
    const batch = this.db.firestore.batch();

    cars.forEach(car => {
      batch.delete(car);
    });

    batch.commit();
  }
```

There are two problems:

1. typescript shows an error for car in `batch.delete(car);`

   > Argument of type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference'.   Property 'firestore' is missing in type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'.
2. If there are for example two cars and each has different categoryId, then `forEach` is triggered twice (for each document, not for document with specific categoryId), but should only one time or maybe there is a better and easier way to delete all docs by specific condition?

UPDATE:

Ok, so this version is working :)

```
public async deleteCol(id: string): Promise<void> {
    const carsList: Observable<firestore.QuerySnapshot> = await this.db.collection('cars', ref => ref.where('categoryId', '==', id)).get();
    const batch = this.db.firestore.batch();
    carsList.pipe(
      mergeMap(cars => cars.docs),
      map((car: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => batch.delete(car.ref))
    ).toPromise().then(() => batch.commit());
  }
```

Comment: #2 happens because you end your query with `.ref.get()`. The `.ref` in there returns a reference to the entire collection, essentially throwing the query you've built away again. So remove `.ref` and simply `.get()` the query results.

Comment: yes, yo're right. I updated my version, so now it's working properly :)

Comment: Good to hear! I vote to close this as a typo, since it's unlikely that other devs making the same mistake will find your question.

Comment: It's not only a type, so I can't do what you want. I added more changes to my code.

Comment: Google proposed elegant solution [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections). There are two code snippets there, so use the seconds one.